# Kindle Fire was on device list but can't debug in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-11.10, kindle-fire

I did:

1) Added

```
0x1949
0x0006
```

to adb_usb.ini

2) Turn on "Unknown sources" in Kindle Fire's Device.

3) Set my app to "debuggable" true.

And I saw Kindle Fire in device list but... **when I "Run As Android Application", an emulator pops up**. How to run my app on KF device?

[image]

Comment: Where is adb_usb file. I usually install usb driver by edit file in /etc/udev

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do the following commands to refresh your adb:
`adb kill-server`,
`sudo adb start-server`

Then try it again. Or instead of using eclipse, do `adb install Android/App/bin/yourappname.apk`